What is the part that holds the two sliding door frames together?
I have sliding doors in my shower. There is a connector that holds together the top rails on which the doors slide.
This connector has loosened/broken and I need to replace it but I don't know what it is called.





It doesn't have a name except whatever they call it in a parts diagram, but that doesn't really matter. It's a proprietary part with a number. Contact the manufacturer, which is the only source for such a thing.

it's probably named corner or corner moulding

Corner Bracket.
